# Joining child results into parent (one to many query)

Tags: sql, language-agnostic, one-to-many, foxpro

Say I've got two tables:

### Parent

id  |  name

### Child

id  |  parentId  |  name

Each parent could have an infinite number of children.  What are some common ways to put a parent's children into the same result set as the parent?  Is there a way to do this without creating a row for each child entry?

I've already realized that it's easier (and probably much more efficient) to just do a second query for the child items, I'm just curious as to what some approaches are.  One approach I found was to use GROUP_CONCAT: http://hussfelt.net/blog/sql/group-join-one-to-many-relationship.

Are there any other methods available to achieve the desired result?  The question is tagged foxpro because it's specific to my implementation, but an agnostic answer would be great too.

Comment: group concat is from MYSQL and coallesce from sql server. but i dont know if they are in foxpro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For processing, you can query in common regardless of back-end, such as

```
select ;
      P.Name as ParentName ;
      C.* ;
   from ;
      Parent P ;
         JOIN Child C ;
            on P.ID = C.ParentID ;
   order by ;
      P.ParentName, ;
      C.Name ;
   into ;
      cursor C_YourResultSet
```

Then, you can scan through the result set and build out whatever else you need, such as a summary of all names per a single parent ID.

Answer (score 2):

First, I strongly recommend against using GROUP_CONCAT.  Grouping multiple data items into a single field is a SQL anti-pattern.

The normal way of returning this data *is* as you say to have one row per child.  This is the most generalised representation of 1:many relationships.

There *may* be a consideration that you don't want to return duplicate data to a client.  For example; if you want all the details of parents and children for a whole school, you may not want the parents' names returned multiple times if the have multiple children in the school.

In such a case it is normal to return two result sets.
1. All the parents, ordered in some manner
2. All the children, including the parent_id to relate the data back, in the *same* order

Although order1 may be "parent name" and the childrens' details don't include the parents' names, you *can still* order by that.

```
SELECT * FROM parents ORDER BY name
SELECT children.* FROM parents INNER JOIN children ON children.parent_id = parents.id ORDER BY parents.name
```

Then, your client itterates through both data sets (as a sorted merge), easily matching the children to parents as they are in the same order.

Whether this technique is of benefit depends on the volume of traffic you're sending over the network.  Normally it's easier to just send the redundant data.  Where that's problematic, this technique works well.